# Port direction mismatch in simple VHDL component

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I am implementing the MIPS processor in VHDL using Quartus II, and one of my components is causing an error that has me completely baffled.

I have the following component:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity HazardDetectionUnit is
    port(       
            --Datapath inputs
            IFIDrt      : in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
            IDEXrt      : in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
            IFIDrs      : in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);

            --Controlpath inputs
            IDEXMemRead : in std_logic;

            PCWrite     : out std_logic;
            IFIDWrite   : out std_logic;
            IDEXFlush   : out std_logic);

end HazardDetectionUnit;

architecture structural of HazardDetectionUnit is

signal same1 : std_logic;
signal same2 : std_logic;
signal NZ1 : std_logic;
signal stall : std_logic;

component comp5
    port(   a       : in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
            b       : in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
            comp_output : out std_logic);
end component;

component zerocomp5
    port ( a        : in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
             zero   : out std_logic);
end component;

begin

    --Port Map
    comparator1 : comp5 port map(IFIDrt, IDEXrt, same1);
    comparator2 : comp5 port map(IDEXrt, IFIDrs, same2);
    nonzero1        : zerocomp5 port map(IDEXrt, NZ1);

    --Concurrent Signal Assignment
    stall <= NZ1 and IDEXMemRead and (same1 or same2);

    --Output Driver
    PCWrite <= not(stall);
    IFIDWrite <= not(stall);
    IDEXFlush <= stall;

end structural;
```

I'm having an issue with the `comp5` component.  The error I'm getting is `Error (12012): Port direction mismatch for entity "MIPS_PROCESSOR:inst|HazardDetectionUnit:inst22|comp5:comparator1" at port "comp_output".  Upper entity is expecting "Input" pin while lower entity is using "Output" pin.`

The sub-component `comp5`, which is a 5-bit equality comparator, is as follows:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity comp5 is
    port(   a       : in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
            b       : in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
            comp_output : out std_logic
            );
end comp5;

architecture structural of comp5 is

signal xor_out : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);

component nxor2_5bit
    port(   a : in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
            b : in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
            o : out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0));
end component;

begin

    --Port Map
    xor_gate : nxor2_5bit port map(a, b, xor_out);

    --Output Driver
    comp_output <= xor_out(4) and xor_out(3) and xor_out(2) and xor_out(1) and xor_out(0);

end structural;
```

How is this possible? The `comp5` component is clearly defined as having two 5-bit inputs, `a` and `b`, and a single one-bit output, `comp_output`.  So why does the compiler insist that `comp_output` is actually an input?

I tried to debug the issue by implementing `HazardDetectionUnit` as a block diagram, but I got the same error.

I don't get it.  `comp5` is just a simple two-input, one-output logic unit.  I've never had an error like this before, and I can't find any posts about a similar error.  Would anyone be able to offer advice?

*Edit:* for completeness, here is the `nxor2_5bit` component:

```
--5-bit NXOR gate.

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity nxor2_5bit is
    port(   a : in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
            b : in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
            o : out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0));
end nxor2_5bit;

architecture structural of nxor2_5bit is
begin

    --Output Driver
    o <= not(a(4) xor b(4)) & not(a(3) xor b(3)) & not(a(2) xor b(2)) & not(a(1) xor b(1)) & not(a(0) xor b(0));

end structural;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your code compiles fine, so any error must be elsewhere. Please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Not that your `comp5` entity will not be bound to the instances of your `comp5` component, because the port names are not the same. (The entity has an output called `comp_output`, whereas the component has an output `same`.) Why are you using component instantiation anyway? Why not use direct instantiation?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  The `same` output was a typo, I've fixed it in the OP, but I am still getting the same error.  I'm using component instantiation because I want to reuse `comp5` in other components.  Although I suppose I could instantiate it directly and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: This code seems fine. If your are using this exact code in your design, the tool is broken. What version of Quartus are you using? I read that olders version of Quartus showed this error for some verilog to VHDL connections.

Comment: I'm using Quartus II v13.0.1, build 232.  Odd though, as I'm only using VHDL and no Verilog.

Comment: In Vivado sometimes there are strange errors, that can be solved by recreating project. You could try that in Quartus too.